# Shell Scripting - Shell Variable not carrying forward value

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
 if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then

    result=$((operand1+operand2))
    result=$((operand1-operand2))
    result=$((operand1*operand2))

     if [[ $result ]] ; then 
        operand1=$result 
        echo "operand 1 is: $result" 
        echo "" 
     else 
        echo Enter operand1 value: 
        read operand1 

     fi

     # Offer choices
     echo 1. Addition
     echo 2. Subtraction
     echo 3. Multiplication
     echo 4. Division
     echo 5. Exit


     echo Enter your choice:
     read choice


     if [[ $choice != 1 && $choice != 2 && $choice != 3 && $choice != 4 && $choice != 5 ]] ; then
         echo Sorry not a valid operator - please try again 
         echo Enter your choice:
         read choice

     fi

     echo Enter operand2 value:
     read operand2

     # get operands and start computing based on the user's choice
     if [[ $choice -eq 1 ]] ; then

         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo Addition of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1+operand2))
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo

     elif [[ $choice -eq 2 ]] ; then

         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo Subtraction of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1-operand2))
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo
     elif [[ $choice -eq 3 ]] ; then

         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo Multiplication of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1*operand2))
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo
     elif [[ $choice -eq 4 && operand2 -eq 0 ]] ; then
         echo Can not divide by 0 please try again 
         echo Please enter operand2
         read operand2
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo Division of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1/operand2))
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo

      elif [[ $choice -eq 4 && operand2 -ne 0 ]] ; then
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo Division of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1/operand2))
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo

     elif [[ $choice -eq 5 ]] ; then
         exit

     else
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo Invalid choice.. Please try again
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo
     fi

   else
         echo ----------------------------------------
         echo You either passed too many parameters or too less
         echo than the optimum requirement.
         echo
         echo This program accepts a maximum of 2 arguments or no
         echo argument at all in order to run successfully.
         echo ----------------------------------------
   fi
done
```

I am working specifically on the top portion of this code. I am trying to have it so the user's result will carry forward for the next operand1. I get getting operand1 = 0 after each calculation. Any idea how to fix this?
operand 1 is: 0

```
1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Division
5. Exit
Enter your choice:
1
Enter operand2 value:
1
----------------------------------------
Addition of 0 and 1 is 1
----------------------------------------

operand 1 is: 0

1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Multiplication
4. Division
5. Exit
Enter your choice:
```

Comment: Have you tried running the code with bash -x?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a sample run that shows the error?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, werdly enough it works when I clear and re input the code in my shell it then calculates all the previous values from before i cleared and adds them although when I start this is what my operand 1 does. Added to question

Comment: What's the purpose of the 3 assignments to `result` at the beginning of the loop body? There is no assignment to `result` that depends on the selected operation.

Comment: Choice 1 prints out `$((operand1+operand2))` but doesn't assign the result to any variable, so `operand1` remains untouched.

Comment: How would you suggest to assign it to the result variable?

Comment: You can improve things by removing `result=$((operand1+operand2))
    result=$((operand1-operand2))
    result=$((operand1*operand2))` at the top - the last one wins, and is 0 in your sample run - and add each of them to your individual cases as appropriate.

Comment: Can you explain what `if [[ $result ]]` is meant to do? I think there might be a better way.

Comment: Okay that works when I add them to each case individually - The if [[result ]]  loop is meant to pick up on if there has been a result and if so have that act as operand1 in the next sequence. I think this is my issue that I've been toggling with as now it does add although operand 1 starts at 0 when it should be prompting the user for the first value

Comment: Hey @MarkPlotnick I think I figured it out. I posted an answer, do you see anything wrong with this? it seems to run correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to reduce the duplicated code. Note the use of `select` to present the menu.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Enter the operation: "     # for the select statement

operand() {
    read -r -p "Enter operand${1} value: "
    echo "$REPLY"
}

operand1=$(operand 1)

while true; do
    select operation in Addition Subtraction Multiplication Division Exit; do
        case $operation in
            Exit) exit ;;
            Addition)       op="+"; break ;;
            Subtraction)    op="-"; break ;;
            Multiplication) op="*"; break ;;
            Division)       op="/"; break ;;
        esac
    done

    while true; do
        operand2=$(operand 2)
        if [[ $operation == "Division" ]] && (( operand2 == 0 )); then
            echo Can not divide by 0 please try again 
        else
            break
        fi
    done

    (( result = operand1 $op operand2 ))

    echo "----------------------------------------"
    echo "$operation of $operand1 and $operand2 is $result"
    echo "----------------------------------------"

    echo "operand 1 is: $result" 
    operand1=$result
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while true
do

         if [[ $result ]] ; then 

            echo "operand 1 is: $result" 
            echo "" 

         else 
            echo Enter operand1 value: 
            read operand1 

         fi

         # Offer choices
         echo 1. Addition
         echo 2. Subtraction
         echo 3. Multiplication
         echo 4. Division
         echo 5. Exit

 
         echo Enter your choice:
         read choice


         if [[ $choice != 1 && $choice != 2 && $choice != 3 && $choice != 4 && $choice != 5 ]] ; then
             echo Sorry not a valid operator - please try again 
             echo Enter your choice:
             read choice

         fi
 
         echo Enter operand2 value:
         read operand2
 
         # get operands and start computing based on the user's choice
         if [[ $choice -eq 1 ]] ; then
 
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Addition of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1+operand2))
             result=$((operand1+operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo

         elif [[ $choice -eq 2 ]] ; then
 
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Subtraction of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1-operand2))
             result=$((operand1-operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         elif [[ $choice -eq 3 ]] ; then
 
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Multiplication of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1*operand2))
             result=$((operand1*operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         elif [[ $choice -eq 4 && operand2 -eq 0 ]] ; then
             echo Can not divide by 0 please try again 
             echo Please enter operand2
             read operand2
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Division of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1/operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo

          elif [[ $choice -eq 4 && operand2 -ne 0 ]] ; then
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Division of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1/operand2))
             result=$((operand1/operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo

         elif [[ $choice -eq 5 ]] ; then
             exit

         else
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Invalid choice.. Please try again
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         fi
done
```

Comment: You _say_ "operand 1 is: $result" but you don't _assign_ operand1 the result value.