# Shell Script - Is not adding result

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do

         if [[ $result ]] ; then 

            echo "operand 1 is: $result" 
            echo "" 

         else 
            echo Enter operand1 value: 
            read operand1 

         fi

         # Offer choices
         echo 1. Addition
         echo 2. Subtraction
         echo 3. Multiplication
         echo 4. Division
         echo 5. Exit

 
         echo Enter your choice:
         read choice


         if [[ $choice != 1 && $choice != 2 && $choice != 3 && $choice != 4 && $choice != 5 ]] ; then
             echo Sorry not a valid operator - please try again 
             echo Enter your choice:
             read choice

         fi
 
         echo Enter operand2 value:
         read operand2
 
         # get operands and start computing based on the user's choice
         if [[ $choice -eq 1 ]] ; then
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Addition of $operand and $operand2 is $((result+operand2))
             result=$((operand1+operand2))

   

         elif [[ $choice -eq 2 ]] ; then
 
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Subtraction of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1-operand2))
             result=$((operand1-operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         elif [[ $choice -eq 3 ]] ; then
 
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Multiplication of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1*operand2))
             result=$((operand1*operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         elif [[ $choice -eq 4 && operand2 -eq 0 ]] ; then
             echo Can not divide by 0 please try again 
             echo Please enter operand2
             read operand2
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Division of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1/operand2))
             result=$((operand1/operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo

          elif [[ $choice -eq 4 && operand2 -ne 0 ]] ; then
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Division of $operand1 and $operand2 is $((operand1/operand2))
             result=$((operand1/operand2))
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo

         elif [[ $choice -eq 5 ]] ; then
             exit

         else
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo Invalid choice.. Please try again
             echo ----------------------------------------
             echo
         fi
done
```

Looking into Result becoming the ongoing count

Operand1 keeps reverting back to operand1 as opposed to the result after the first calculation any idea of how to make sure the operand stays as the totalling result after the first prompt - essentially so that the user does not have to enter operand1 again

Comment: If you could slim this down to just a few lines that show the problem that would help a lot

Comment: What is the actual question? are you trying to keep `operand1` so that only the `choices` is asked on the second time?

Comment: Where are you doing the assignment `operand1=$result`?  If you want the value of `operand1` to change, you need to change it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I answered this in a comment to your answer in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66319034/shell-scripting-shell-variable-not-carrying-forward-value)